# Create table syntax error SQLite

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error, create-table

I get a syntax error when I create a  four rows table in my SQLite and I don't know why. This is my code.

```
 private static final String TABLE_PRIMERO = "jugadors";

// Jugadors Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_ALTURA = "altura";
private static final String KEY_PARTIDO = "partido";

int oldVersion=1;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_JUGADORS_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE_PRIMERO " + TABLE_PRIMERO + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ALTURA + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PARTIDO + " TEXT"
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_JUGADORS_TABLE1);


}

//Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRIMERO);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String CREATE_JUGADORS_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE_PRIMERO " + TABLE_PRIMERO + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_ALTURA + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_PARTIDO + " TEXT"
        + ")";
```

This should be something like

```
String CREATE_JUGADORS_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRIMERO + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_ALTURA + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_PARTIDO + " TEXT"
        + ")";
```

The `TABLE` is a keyword with a specific meaning.